# Can you load a custom Public Suffix file in Guava?

Tags: guava

I'm using Guava's `InternetDomainName.from(domain).topPrivateDomain().toString()` to extract the "top private domain" from full domain names.

e.g.
for `bbc.co.uk`, it would list `.co.uk` as the "top private domain", as opposed to simply `.uk`.

Unfortunately, the list it's based on (the Mozilla Public Suffix List, included in `com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixPatterns`) is lacking certain commercial TLDs which effectively function as "top private domains".

e.g.: `wordpress.com`, `wix.com`

Does Guava offer the option to load an amended list, using Mozilla's original `.dat` format, which has the additions included, and use that instead of the hard coded one? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, not currently. See [this feature request](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1123).